# i want to generate a random number from 0 to 20. go through the random number and keep adding the number to a list until a duplicate & stop & print

Tags: python, python-3.8

IN PYTHON

```
number = random.randint(1, 10)
array = []
for num in number:
    if num not in array:
        array.append(num)
    else: 
        print(array)
```

I ALSO TRIED

```
number = random.randint(1,10)
array = []
while number not in array:
     array.append(number)
if number in array:
      print(array)
```

please what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: If you add a "break" to the very end of your first sample, it will work.  And if you remove the `if number in array:` from your second sample, it will also work.

Comment: Although, if you want numbers from 0 to 20, I'm not sure why you are telling randint to give you numbers from 1 to 10.

Comment: it is not generating anything. the code is supposed to go through the random numbers and if the random number is not in the list . it should add it to the list. and if the number happened to be in the list. it should print out all the number that the list has appended so far including the duplicate

Comment: Your issue is that you're only generating one random number, since you're calling `random.randint` *outside* your loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts i made a mistake in the question am asking

Comment: Ack, @CrazyChucky, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code is quite ok, you just need to generate a new number each time

```
array = []
number = random.randint(1, 10)
while number not in array:
    array.append(number)
    number = random.randint(1, 10)

print(array)
```

Comment: Did you even TRY this code, @user8801738?  That's exactly what it does,

Comment: @TimRoberts i have since figured out that what the code does. am new to python so pls bear with me. thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @azro i have since figured out that what the code does. am new to python so pls bear with me. thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

Check the list by comparing the size of the list to the size of the set version of the list:

```py
from random import randint

array = []
while len(array) == len(set(array)):
    number = randint(1, 10)
    array.append(number)

print(l)
```

Comment: That's cute, but it's way less efficient than the "number not in array" methods.

Comment: Yea that's true. I just wanted to offer a more interesting method involving sets. Oh I also didn't feel like copying and pasting lol